# Positioning an element between two elements if there is room, but below if necessary

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to center my post title between two navigation buttons.
On small screens, I want the navigation buttons to be together at the top, and for the title to wrap below.

Desired result on large screens:

[image: Desired result on large screens]

Desired result on small screens:

[image: Desired result on large screens]

The post title, date, and tags are contained in one flex-grow div.

```css
#post-head {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  background-color: @col-3-1;
  margin-left: -1vw;
  margin-right: -1vw;
}

#post-meta {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: maven;
  font-weight: 700;
  // background: linear-gradient(lighten(@col-3-1, 10) 0%, @col-3-1 20%);
}

#post-title {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}

#post-date {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: fade(white, 80);
}

#post-tags {
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#post-tags>div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 12px 3px 12px;
  background-color: fade(black, 20);
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid fade(white, 20);
}

#post-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#post-nav>div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="post-head">
  <div id="post-nav">
    <div>
      < Previous Post</div>
        <div>Next Post ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="post-meta">
      <div id="post-title">Post Title</div>
      <div id="post-date">12 July, 2022</div>
      <div id="post-tags">
        <div>Tag 1</div>
        <div>Tag 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of what your code looks like now (in the question body itself; not linked)

Answer (score 1):

I had to adjust quite a lot - both HTML and CSS - to make it work the way you want so I suggest you dig into the details.

Essential is the use of a media query to separate small screen styles from large screen styles an the order property for flex items. You can find more about media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```css
#post-head {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  background-color: @col-3-1;
  margin-left: -1vw;
  margin-right: -1vw;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#post-meta {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: maven;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100vw;
}

#post-title {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#post-date {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: fade(white, 80);
}

#post-tags {
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#post-tags>div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 12px 3px 12px;
  background-color: fade(black, 20);
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid fade(white, 20);
}

#post-head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#post-head>div:nth-child(1),
#post-head>div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  min-width: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  max-height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  #post-meta {
    width: initial;
  }
  #post-head {
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  }
  #post-previous {
    order: 1;
  }
  #post-next {
    order: 3;
  }
  #post-meta {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="post-head">
  <div id="post-previous">&lt; Previous Post</div>
  <div id="post-next">Next Post &gt;</div>
  <div id="post-meta">
    <div id="post-title">Post Title</div>
    <div id="post-date">12 July, 2022</div>
    <div id="post-tags">
      <div>Tag 1</div>
      <div>Tag 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Gerard!  Today I learned about media queries.  I think a grid layout is the way to go here, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have done by using CSS Grid.

```css
body{
background-color:#42243C;
color:white;
}

#post-nav{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows:1fr 2fr;

text-align:center;

}

.prev, .next{
 text-align:center;
 border:1px solid black;
 
}

.prev{
margin-left:20px;
}

.next{
margin-right:20px;
}


#post-tags{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
grid-gap:5px;
}

.t1{
text-align:right;
}

.t2{
text-align:left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
 #post-meta{
    grid-row:2/3;
    grid-column:1/3;
    
 } 
 
   #post-nav{
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
      text-align:center;
      justify-self:center;
      grid-column-gap:20px;
      grid-row-gap:10px;
}



}
```

```html
<div id="post-head">
  <div id="post-nav">
    <div class="prev"> &lt; Previous Post</div>
    <div id="post-meta">
      <div id="post-title">Post Title</div>
      <div id="post-date">12 July, 2022</div>
      <div id="post-tags">
        <div class="t1">Tag 1</div>
        <div class="t2">Tag 2</div>
      </div>
      
   </div>
    <div class="next">Next Post &gt;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  This works great except for one problem - in the wide format, how can we remove the extra space reserved for the blank second row in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Between the helpful answers given by Arman and Gerard, I was able to get what I want!

I think a grid layout is definitely the better option here.  The key was to set the `grid-template-rows` property to `auto 0fr` to prevent extra space being reserved in the grid.  Also, I increased the number of columns so that it can be evenly divided when the navigation buttons are put on a new row.

```
#post-head{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:auto 0fr;
    text-align:center;
}

.post-nav.prev{
    grid-column:1/2;
}
.post-nav.next{
    grid-column:4/5;
}

#post-meta{
    grid-row: 1/2;
    grid-column:2/4;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    #post-meta{
        grid-row:2/3;
        grid-column: 1/5;
    }
    .post-nav.prev{
        grid-column:1/3;
    }
    .post-nav.next{
        grid-column:3/5;
    }
}
```

```
<div id="post-head">
    <div class="post-nav prev">&lt; Previous Post</div>
    <div id="post-meta">
        <div id="post-title">Post Title</div>
        <div id="post-date">12 July, 2022</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-nav next">Next Post &gt;</div>
</div>
```